# Is it possible to read/write multiple properties of an entity into a single column using entity framework 6? How?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, serialization, customization

Given models below (**User** and **Xyz**), I want Entity Framework to write the Xyz properties of a User into a single column, instead of creating and writing them into three columns (**Xyz_X**, **Xyz_Y**, **Xyz_Z**).

1. It it possible to customize the **serializer** / **deserializer** for Entity Framework to do this?
2. How?

Thank you!

## Models:

```cs
public class Xyz
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator string(Xyz d) => $"{d.X};{d.Y};{d.Z}";

    public static implicit operator Xyz(string s)
    {
        var separators = new char[] { ';' };
        var t = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return new Xyz
        {
            X = int.Parse(t[0]),
            Y = int.Parse(t[1]),
            Z = int.Parse(t[2]),
        };
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Xyz Xyz { get; set; }
}
```

### Database tables for the models described above

#### Users table now (currently):

| ID | Name | Xyz_X | Xyz_Y | Xyz_Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Bob | -1 | 999 | 777 |

#### Users table with customized **serialization** / **deserialization** (what I want):

| ID | Name | Xyz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 0;1;2 |
| 2 | Bob | -1;999;777 |

---

## Update: using a workaround

Since **ValueConverter** is not supported in **EF6** (see comments!) and I cannot change/rewrite/migrate whole project to **Core 3.1**, I used following workaround:

1. Added a second property **DbXyz** to **User** class
2. Added **NotMapped** attribute to **Xyz** property of **User** class

Now **EF** ignores property **Xyz** when it comes to reads/writes it, but property **DbXyz**, which is abused as converter for the property **Xyz**.

*It is important to comment and name the new "converter" property **DbXyz** so that other developers understand not use the get/set in their algorithm and use the **Xyz** property instead.*

```cs
public class Xyz
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{X};{Y};{Z}";

    public static implicit operator string(Xyz d) => d.ToString();

    public static implicit operator Xyz(string s)
    {
        var separators = new char[] { ';' };
        var t = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return new Xyz
        {
            X = int.Parse(t[0]),
            Y = int.Parse(t[1]),
            Z = int.Parse(t[2]),
        };
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Xyz Xyz { get; set; }

    // Used only to read/write from database!
    public string DbXyz
    {
        get => Xyz.ToString();
        set => Xyz= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thank you! I have followed your link and searched for *ValueConverter* for **EF 6** . It seems to me that one can find the ValueConverter class only in Core and .NET 5.0 but not in 4.7 with EF6. Am I wrong?

Comment: Value Conversions is an EF Core feature.   EF Core 3.1 is the last version of EF Core to support .NET Framework 4.7.  With EF6 you can approximate this with NotMapped properties.